# Repeatedly selecting groups out of loaded SVG with Snap.svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, snap.svg

I'm kinda new with the whole SVG business, now I'm stumbling upon a problem that I really don't understand.

I'm animating icons at the moment and noticed that repeatedly selecting g's and applying them doesn't work for me. For the sake of the question I've made an example. What I would like it to do is: Load svg > Apply the first 'G' with mask > on click animate the child 'G' upwards > clear > Select a specific 'G' (this time again the first one) > animate it from the bottom to the center

For some reason in stead of grabbing the first 'G' it iterates over the 'G's in the SVG. I've tried this with using Select with Id's, but it's giving me the same troubles.

Sooo what am I doing wrong?

html

```
<svg id="svg"></svg>
```

js

```
var s = Snap("#svg");
s.attr({ viewBox: "0 0 300 300" });
var bigCircle = s.circle(150, 150, 100);
var bigCircle2 = s.circle(150, 150, 100);

bigCircle2.attr({       
    fill:"none",
    stroke: "#0000e6",
    strokeWidth: 6
});


bigCircle.attr({
    fill: "#fff",
    stroke: "#fff",
    strokeWidth: 6
});    

Snap.load("images/numbers.svg", function (f) {

var apply = function(number){
    g = f.select("svg g:nth-child("+number+")");
    s.append(g);
    g.attr({
        mask: bigCircle,
    });   
    p = g.select("g");      
};   

apply(1); //Please give me the first g in the svg

var g_animate = function(){ 
    p.animate({ transform: 't0,-200' }, 500, mina.easeout, function(){
        p.remove();         
        apply(1); //Let's repeat the first g in the svg             
        p.attr({transform: 't0,200'});  
        p.animate({ transform: 't0,0' }, 500, mina.easein)
        })
    };

$("#svg").click(function(){   
    g_animate();
});
});
```

loaded svg

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <g>
    <path d="M162.367,212.803v-34.396h-58.358v-11.016l56.04-80.193h18.357v78.068h17.584v13.141h-17.584v34.396H162.367z
         M162.367,165.266v-41.932c0-6.57,0.193-13.14,0.58-19.71h-0.58c-3.865,7.343-6.957,12.753-10.436,18.551l-30.724,42.705v0.387
        H162.367z"/>
    <rect fill="none" width="300" height="300"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g>
    <g>
    <path d="M115.411,193.479c4.83,2.898,15.846,7.73,27.826,7.73c21.642,0,28.599-13.721,28.406-24.35
        c-0.193-17.584-16.039-25.119-32.464-25.119h-9.469v-12.754h9.469c12.367,0,28.019-6.377,28.019-21.256
        c0-10.049-6.377-18.938-22.029-18.938c-10.048,0-19.71,4.444-25.12,8.309l-4.638-12.367c6.764-4.83,19.517-9.662,33.043-9.662
        c24.734,0,35.943,14.687,35.943,29.952c0,13.141-7.924,24.155-23.189,29.759v0.387c15.459,2.898,27.826,14.493,28.02,32.077
        c0,20.098-15.846,37.682-45.796,37.682c-14.106,0-26.474-4.443-32.657-8.502L115.411,193.479z"/>
    <rect fill="none" width="300" height="300"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g>
    <g>
    <path d="M109.903,213.865v-10.435l13.334-12.947c32.077-30.531,46.764-46.764,46.764-65.7c0-12.754-5.991-24.542-24.735-24.542
        c-11.4,0-20.869,5.798-26.666,10.628l-5.411-11.98c8.503-7.149,21.062-12.754,35.362-12.754c27.054,0,38.454,18.551,38.454,36.522
        c0,23.188-16.812,41.933-43.285,67.439l-9.854,9.275v0.387h56.231v14.106H109.903z"/>
    <rect fill="none" width="300" height="300"/>
    </g>
</g>

<g>
    <g>
    <path d="M154.541,103.043h-0.387l-21.835,11.787l-3.285-12.946l27.439-14.687h14.494v125.605h-16.426V103.043z"/>
    <rect fill="none" width="300" height="300"/>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't keep repeating the same g element, as you remove it from the DOM with this...

```
p.remove();
```

So next time it selects, it the 2nd initial g will now be the first one.

Edit:

Its also worth looking at what happens with 'append'. If you append an element from a fragment (the data loaded from the file) into the DOM, then that element is no longer in the fragment f. So if you now select a new element, it will be the next g element (as the other one has been removed and added to the DOM).  So if you wanted the SAME element, you want to use a css selector on s rather than f.

I'd be tempted to use a selectAll initially on the svg to get all of the g elements into an array and use those to reference them, it may feel more intuitive.

Comment: Ah wow thanks Ian! So how can I clear the element from the 'canvas' without removing it entirely?

Comment: Oh, actually removing the p.remove(); does not solve the problem. For me it still does not apply the intended 'g'. Does the element 'disappear' from the loaded svg after applying it? I've updated the link to the live demo.